# SQL Server connection string "To few arguments"

Tags: c++, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, connection-string, visual-studio-express

I guess the solution is simple. I'm trying to connect to a SQL Express Server on my computer using the following line:

```
pConnection->Open("Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Mydata;User Id = Test;Password = Test;False");//(connectionstring,userID,pwd,longoption);
```

Two questions: Do I have to put every part of the connection string in "quotes" or simply the entire string? What is the "longoption" I am prompted for?

The error I get right now is: "To few arguments in function call"

I'm glad for any help. Have a nice day!
Lumpi

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what language you are using, but I'm betting that last false is not a part of the connection string, but a second parameter to Open();

```
pConnection->Open("Data Source=PETERPAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyData", "Test", "Test", False);
```

Comment: Uups, I forgot, I am using C++ from a console app written using VS2010express.

Comment: @Lumpi - I would also look out for any "\" in the string, and try with a "\\" instead.

Answer (score 0):

check out the website [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/). They'll give you a wide option of what to send to the database that you have. A copy-paste of these connectionstrings should work just fine. I think that the one closest to what you describe would be [SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).